# Java file address during processing of contents

Tags: java

I am passing in directory into java and it will search for few keywords in each file. Then i want to output the keyword with the file it came from. Is there a method that i can call after reading input from a string and comparing it to know from which file it is?

Comment: What object do you want to call the method on?

Comment: Why dont you try and read the javadoc for java.io.File ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) in Commons IO has some methods that make reading the text from files trivial. Look at the lineIterator(...) and the readLines(...) methods.